# Total Electrical failure Mondeo 1.8tdci 2008

Tags: electrical, ford, battery, alternator, lights

While charging a flat battery all on the Mondeo all of the electrics failed (lights, dash, not starting, Windows, ect) when I installed a new battery on the Mondeo still nothing. Any ideas on what needs fixing.

Comment: Sounds like a bad fusible link somewhere between battery and main fuse box.

Comment: here is a link to the high amp fusible link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwD7MazcAdU not sure if it is the same one as in your car.

Answer (score 0):

Charge the battery properly or replace it, then test the electrics.

The charger probably does not have the ouptut to run all those items.

Comment: Replaced with a new battery and still none of the electrics worked, all the small fuses are intact. Thank you for the last reply.

Comment: @DarkieBluebell Did you check the fusible link mentioned by narkeleptk in the comment to your first question? The fusible link is not the same as the "small fuses," and will be located in the engine compartment. Its failure will produce the symptom (total electrical failure) you report.